# SASS/SCSS Changing property name in a for loop

Tags: html, sass

I'm trying to learn SCSS and while I understand how loops can be used to assign different values to a property, is it possible to use them to generate different properties?

I'm trying to create a site which would have 4 divs,

```
<div id="divContainer">
  <div><div>
  <div><div>
  <div><div>
  <div><div>
</div>
```

each positioned relatively to a different corner of their parent, and the css itself would look like this:

```
.divContainer:nth-child(1) {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  top: 20px;
}

.divContainer:nth-child(2) {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
}

.divContainer:nth-child(3) {
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
}

.divContainer:nth-child(4) {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 20px;
}
```

I tried defining a list of these sides and then use the nth function to define property names, which isn't working:

```
$sides: ('top', 'right', 'bottom', 'left', 'top');

@for $i from 1 through 4 {
  .divContainer:nth-child(#{$i}) {
    position: absolute;
    nth($sides, $i): 20px;
    nth($sides, $i+1): 20px;
  }
}
```

I didn't find any mention of such a possibility in SASS docs, so any help or explenation would be greatly appreciated.

P.S. This is the first time I'm asking a question on stackoverflow, if I did anything incorrectly, feel free to enlighten me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there, you just forgot to wrap the generated property names with `#{...}` for [string interpolation](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/interpolation):

```
$sides: ('top', 'right', 'bottom', 'left', 'top');

@for $i from 1 through 4 {
  .divContainer:nth-child(#{$i}) {
    position: absolute;
    #{nth($sides, $i)}: 20px;
    #{nth($sides, $i+1)}: 20px;
  }
}
```